# Scala - Map2 function on Option --> flatMap vs. Map vs. For-Comprehension

Tags: scala

Option is used for dealing with partiality in Scala, but we can also lift ordinary functions to the context of Options in order to handle errors. When implementing the function map2 I am curious on how to know when to use which functions. Consider the following implementation:

```
def map2[A,B,C] (ao: Option[A], bo: Option[B]) (f: (A,B) => C): Option[C] =
    ao flatMap {aa =>
      bo map {bb =>
        f(aa, bb)
```

aa is of type A, and bb is of type B which is then fed to F, giving us a C. However, if we do the following:

```
def map2_1[A,B,C] (ao: Option[A], bo: Option[B]) (f: (A,B) => C): Option[C] =
    ao flatMap {aa =>
      bo flatMap {bb =>
        f(aa, bb)
```

aa is still of type A, and bb is still of type B, yet we will have to wrap the last call in Some(f(aa, bb)) in order to get an Option[C] instead of a regular C. Why is this? What does it mean to flatten on BO here?

Last and not least, one could do the simpler:

```
def map2_2[A,B,C] (ao: Option[A], bo: Option[B]) (f: (A,B) => C): Option[C] = for {
    as <- ao 
    bs <- bo 
} yield(f(as,bs))
```

I know that for-comprehensions are syntactic sugar for ForEach'es, maps and flatmaps etc, but how do I, as a developer, know that the compiler will choose MAP with bs <- bo, and not flatMap?

I think I am on the verge of understanding the difference, yet nested flatmaps confuse me.

Comment: You only need to follow the types, `flatMap` expects a function that returns an `Option[B]` whereas `map` only a `B` thus if you use `flatMap` for the nested call, you need to wrap the result of `f` on a `Option` to make it typecheck. - About `for` the last `<-` will desugar to a `map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the last question first, the developer knows what the compiler will do with `for` because the behaviour is defined and predictable: All `<-` turn into `flatMap` except the last one which will be either `map` or `foreach` depending on whether or not there is a `yield`.

The broader question seems to be about the difference between `map` and `flatMap`. The difference should be clear from the signatures e.g. for `List` these are the (simplified) signatures:

```
def map[B]    (f: A => B)      : List[B]
def flatMap[B](f: A => List[B]): List[B]
```

So `map` just replaces the values in a `List` with new values by applying `f` to each element of type `A` to generate a `B`.

`flatMap` generates a new list by concatenating the results of calling `f` on each element of the original `List`. It is equivalent to `map` followed by `flatten` (hence the name).

Intuitively, `map` is a one-for-one replacement whereas `flatMap` allows each element in the original `List` to generate 0 or more new elements.